# Show that projection transforms open sets to open sets

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m, m \leq n,  f(x_{1},...,x_{n})=(x_{1},...,x_{m})$$ transforms open sets to open sets. I think it sufficies to show that it transforms open disk into open disk, I'm not sure why and how to start working on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B=B((x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n), r)$ is an open ball in $\Bbb R^n$, then show that $f[B]= B((x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_m), r)$ where the last ball is taken in $\Bbb R^m$ of course. The inclusion from left to right is obvious as $f$ decreases distances (we're leaving out $n-m$ coordinates with contributions $\ge 0$ under the square root), and for the other inclusion we can add $x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_n$ to a point in $\Bbb R^m$ and the distance to the centre of $B$ will stay the same as its distance to $(x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_m)$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Every norm (hence topology stemming from this norm, *i.e.* the natural topology) on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is equivalent to any other norm. Take the norm $\Vert x \Vert_{\infty} = \max_{i = 1, \dots, d} |x_i|$, so that your open disks $B(x, r)$ are of the form $A_1 \times A_2 \times \dots \times A_d$ with $A_i = (x_i-r, x_i+r)$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to figure something out :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{R^m}$ are Banach spaces, and $f$ is a surjective and continuous linear operator, then by the open mapping theorem, $f$ is an open map.

Disclaimer: This theorem is probably "out of reach" from a general topology setting.

Comment: I didn't have that theorem but I'll check it, it is very helpful!